# How do I show specific projects of each user for the admin.?

Tags: php, laravel-5

The admin of the application has access to list each projects of a user. Write now I am able to list the projects but they all are listed together no matter the unique id of the URL.

```
   //    Admin form case controller
    public function adminforms (Project $project){
        $users = User::get();
     return view('smiledesign.adminforms', compact('users', 'project'));
 } 
///Records controller
    public function records(user $users, project $project){
        $project = project::get();

        $users = user::get();

        return view ('/smiledesign/records' , compact( 'users','project'));
    }
```

```
<table class="table">
            <thead>
                    <tr>
                            <th>Dr Name</th>
                            <th>User Id</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                    </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
       @foreach ($users as $user)
             <tr>
                 <td> <a href="/smiledesign/{{$user->id}}/records">{{$user->name}}</a></td>
                 <td> <a href="/smiledesign/{{$user->id}}/records">{{$user->id}}</a></td>
                 <td> <a href="/smiledesign/{{$user->id}}/records">{{$user->email}}</a></td>
             </tr>

         </tbody>
         @endforeach
     </table>
```

```
// Records view
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="table_id">
            <thead>
                    <tr>
                            <th>Case Number</th>
                            <th>Case Form</th>
                            <th>Patient Name</th>
                            <th>Date Created</th>
                            <th>Status</th>
                    </tr>
            </thead>
            @foreach ($project as $project)
            <tbody>

             <tr>

                 <td> <a href="/smiledesign/{{$project->id}}/show">{{$project->case_number}}</a></td>

                 @if ($project->services0)
                 <td> <a href="/smiledesign/{{$project->id}}/show">{{$project->services0}}</a></td> 
                 @elseif ($project->services1)
                 <td> <a href="/smiledesign/{{$project->id}}/show">{{$project->services1}}</a></td> 
                 @elseif ($project->services2)
                 {{-- <td> <a href="/smiledesign/{{$project->id}}/show">{{$project->services2 . '  '  . $project->mockup0}}</a></td>  --}}
                 <td> <a href="/smiledesign/{{$project->id}}/show">{{$project->services2 . '  '  . $project->mockup0 . ' ' . $project->mockup1}}</a></td> 

                 @endif
                 <td> <a href="/smiledesign/{{$project->id}}/show">{{$project->first_name . ' ' . $project->last_name}}</a></td>
                 <td> <a href="/smiledesign/{{$project->id}}/show">{{$project->created_at}}</a></td>
                 <td> <a href="/smiledesign/{{$project->id}}/show">{{$project->concerns}}</a></td> 
             </tr>

         </tbody>
         @endforeach

     </table>
```

What I wanna see is each project of a specific user when I click The link from the adminforms user. Instead, every link I go I see all projects of all users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relationship between the projects and users should be defined in the database and in the models themselves.

### Database:

In my interpretation, a user can work on multiple projects and a project can have multiple users, this would be a many to many relationship. With this conclusion, I would go for an abstracted table setup like so:

- table users has an id field.
- table projects has an id field.
- table project_users has an id field(always required for laravel), a user_id field(foreign key to users.id) and a project_id field(foreign key to projects.id). Do not forget to add a unique key which combines user_id and project id, there is no need for duplicate definitions.

### Model relationships:

#### Project

```
function users()
{
    $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'project_users', 'project_id', 'user_id');
}
```

#### User

```
function projects()
{
    $this->belongsToMany(Project::class, 'project_users', 'user_id', 'project_id');
}
```

If you read [this piece of documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many), it will all make sense.

### Query

```
$users = User::with('projects')->get();
```

or

```
$projects = Project:with('users')->get();
```

Now every user instance has a projects collection. If they do not, then you need to add a record to the database coupling a project to that user.

### Showing results

```
foreach($users as $user)
{
    foreach($user->projects as $project)
    { 
        echo "$user->name works on project $project->name" . PHP_EOL;
    } 
}
```

or

```
foreach($projects as $project)
{
    foreach($project->users as $user)
    { 
        echo "$user->name works on project $project->name" . PHP_EOL;
    } 
}
```

### Sidenote

My instructions are optimized for performance. You could also just call `->projects` on the `$user` without using the `with('projects')` in the query, but that will mean that you will trigger a query on the spot. As this kind of code is prone to being used in `foreach` statements, you could be doing queries in `foreach` statements which is referred to a [N+1 query problem](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabcontrib/article/n_plus_one/).